# Android and JSP - Working with objects

Tags: android, jsp, service

I'm a student trying to dive into the world of "complex web-enabled applications" for Android.
I had good tries making Android applications that call php functions, have JSON or XML responses and results, serialize objects and so on...

It really can work for simple projects, IMHO. For projects that require an increased complexity and control, I really would like to try something else.

Since Android apps are made in Java, I'm thinking it could be great if I could work with Java objects in Android and storing/retrieving Java objects in the server side too. Java Server Pages could be an answer, since I can embed Java code into HTML pages/HTTP services.

Is possible (and comfortable) to achieve this? Can I work with "local objects" in my Android app and with "remote objects" in my JSP app storing them, for example, in a remote database?

What could be an alternative?

I hope I've been clear. Thank you!

Comment: I fail to see the difference between what you have been using (JSON/XML) and what you are proposing. You might want to elaborate a bit further.

Comment: Maybe I've not been clear, after all.
Making it simple, I'd like to upload and store a real Java object on my server, *not* a representation of its contents with strings.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring android](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/) as HTTP client and [ORMlite](http://ormlite.com/) in the client side has been my salvation in many android projects. What I generally do is have this in the client side and in the server side use a Spring MVC server. But if your server is written in Php there's no problem. With this environment I can work with object in the client side and in the server side, never touching json/xml. I'm making a tumblr client in android. In this package I've all the things related to the Http client [rest package](https://github.com/astinx/Giffy/tree/master/src/com/kimboo/giffy/server/rest). Look how I use it in this class [example](https://github.com/astinx/Giffy/blob/master/src/com/kimboo/giffy/services/GifManagerService.java#L80).